# Не получается сделать пуш на GitHub

Tags: git, github

Проблема в следющем: я создал новый профиль на GitHub, создал там репозиторий, клонировал этот репозиторий себе на локалку, добавил туда проект Django, сделал сайт. Пришло время коммитить и пушить код, однако возникает проблема. Когда я пушу код, то выдаётся эта ошибка:

```
remote: Permission to ArtBoss/Shop.git denied to CodeArts7.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ArtBoss/Shop.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Понял, что ошибка связана с тем, что локально я до сих пор с CodeArts7 нахожусь. Через команды:

```
git cofig user.name 'ArtBoss' и git config user.email 'новый мэйл'
```

поменял почту и имя. Командой:

```
git commit --amend --reset-author
```

обновил инфу и она вроде бы обновилась, однако при пуше всё равно получаю такое же сообщение. В чём дело и как исправить, не могу понять?

Comment: Может какой-нибудь credential manager/IDE закешировали/сохранили логин/пароль для доступа к github и оно продолжает логиниться как CodeArts7 и их нужно поменять?

Comment: *"поменял почту и имя"* - эти почта и имя используются для указания авторства коммитов. А вам необходимо настроить авторизацию. Создавайте себе ssh ключ и т.д.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/ru/authentication

Comment: @user7860670 Ssh действительно решил проблему, благодарю! Не знал, как сделать авторизацию, теперь в курсе...Подскажите, пожалуйста, а через ssh же могу также клонировать приватный репозиторий, который я создал? А что нужно будет напарнику для клонирования?